# Anchor Link to same page in Angular with style change doesn´t work with $anchorScroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple view in Angular with a menu. Each element in the menu is a link to a particular part of same page. I´m using $snchorScroll to implement this and it´s working fine. However, when I click on any menu item, its style should change to active, so it is marked in blue.

I can´t understand why this is working only when I click twice in same link. I mean, first time I click on a menu item, its class is not set to active. The second time it does.

This is not working in my local code. What is my surprise when trying to develop a plunker to ilustrate the problem, the plunker is working perfectly.

So, please find the plunker that is working fine, but, any idea, how it´s not working in my development environment?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6dElweMizpPHD1ZphksX

**UPDATE:** In development, if I remove the calls to $anchorScroll the styles switch work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the ng-click action to change the active style is executed before scrollTo (with $anchorScroll), I realized active style was overwritten when $anchorScroll executes, because it reload the page and the controller. So, what I did is to store the active style in a service and load it when controller reloads. Then works perfectly.

My controller:

```
 .controller ('AboutCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll, AboutService) {              

        var setActiveClass = function() {

            $scope.whatIsItStyle = "";
            $scope.howIsPossibleStyle = "";
            $scope.teamStyle = "";

            if ($scope.step == "whatIsIt") {
                $scope.whatIsItStyle = "active";
            } else if ($scope.step == "howIsPossible") {
                $scope.howIsPossibleStyle = "active";
            } else if ($scope.step == "team") {
                $scope.teamStyle = "active";
            } 
        }; 

        $scope.step = AboutService.getStep();       
        setActiveClass();       


        $scope.setStep = function(step) {               
            $scope.step = step;
            AboutService.setStep(step);
            setActiveClass();
        };                              
    })
```